# PHP Facebook or twitter-like news feed

Tags: php, feed

Hey guys, I'm creating a website and I'm wondering if any of you know how I can create a PHP facebook-like news feed or one similar to twitter. I prefer facebook's, so if you know of a way or you know of a helpful tutorial, that would greatly help. Thank you.

Comment: I recommend javascript for output displays and php for database gathering and retrieving.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? I'm sort of new to this, especially javascript. But I know how to store stuff in the database, just not the Javascript part.

Comment: I don't exactly understand the question. Are you asking about how to make a list of posts look like the fbook newsfeed? Or about how to store newsfeed items in a database?

Comment: I know how to store them in the database, just how to display them, and just those of friends, and auto-refresh.

Comment: Well showing just the ones from friends is something that you must put into your application logic (if(post_author in friends) then post). Autorefresh you can do with AJAX: http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp

Comment: And if you need some more help on AJAX, here is a tutorial on how to write your own AJAX function. http://bit.ly/haqa4P

Comment: facebook has actually patented their newsfeed. although it seems to be used everywhere anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check news every 10 seconds via javascript. And then, javascript runs *generate.php* . Generate.php generates a feed (i.e. xml feed)